# How to pause a UIImageView animation

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, animation, uiimageview

I have an animation that I'm displaying using a UIImageView:

```
imageView.animationImages = myImages;
imageView.animationDuration = 3;
[imageView startAnimating];
```

I know I can stop it using stopAnimating, but what I want is to be able to pause it. The reason is that when you call stop, none of your animation images are displayed, whereas I would like the last one that is up at the time when I hit a button to stay up.

I have tried setting the duration to a much larger number, but that causes all the images to disappear as well. There must be a really basic way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hmmm...since no one seems to know I guess it's not possible.

I went ahead and wrote my own `UIView`, with a `UIImageView` `subview`, that uses an `NSTimer` to switch between images. The advantage of this is that I can pause and resume the timer at my leisure, and performance doesn't seem to be an issue.

Answer (score 18):

This code will pause an animated object at its current position in the animation process. If you record other variables like the time or progress or whatever you need, it should be fairly trivial to resume the animation again.

```
UIView *viewBeingAnimated = //your view that is being animated
viewBeingAnimated.frame = [[viewBeingAnimated.layer presentationLayer] frame];
[viewBeingAnimated.layer removeAllAnimations];
//when user unpauses, create new animation from current position.
```

Comment: i too wanted to pause my animation..In this code wat is presentationLayer?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11103227/pause-uiimageview-animation) the answer that helped me to achive this.

Answer (score 3):

@oddmeter just a little edit:

```
    animatedView.animationImages = images; //images is your array
    [animatedView startAnimating];


    //Then when you need to pause;

[animatedView stopAnimating]; //Important!!
    animatedView.image = [images objectAtIndex: 0];
```

Comment: This only works if you happen to pause right at the frame located at index 0.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2009/qa1673.html

It basically tells you what you need to do to pause/resume any `CALayer` based animation.

If you feel uncomfortable using `CALayer` methods on `UIImageView` controlled animation, you could always just make the `UIImage` array based animation yourself. The code needed is very short, you can take it from here: http://rssv2.blogspot.com/2011/04/animating-series-of-images-with-calayer.html

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to set the image property as well as the `animationImages` property. Doing this will display the static image when the `UIImageView` has its animations stopped.

Assuming your class is a subclass of `UIImageView` and have an `NSMutableArray` of images, do the following:

```
self.animationImages = images;
//yes, I'm skipping the step to check and make sure you have at least one
//element in your array
self.image = [images objectAtIndex: 0];
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can take a screenshot of the last animated image and display that?