# Pause UIImageview Animation

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I want to pause `UIImageView animation` and based on my research found that you can stop the animation of the images but you cannot pause the sequence. By calling statement `stop animating` on the `UIImageView` then it stops the animation and blanks the image view.

To pause the animation of UIImages one has to use `NSTimer`.

I m already using one `NSTimer` in app for loading `view controllers` one after the other at different time intervals. I have a slide show of `UIImages` in each `view controller`.

Issue is when Timer is paused `view controllers` are paused from loading further but the `view controller` which is on display at that time still shows the slide show of `UIImages` of that `view controller` repeatedly until pause is resumed. So I want to pause that slideshow too.

This is where i m using the `NSTimer`

```
-(void)playpauseAction:(id)sender {
if([audioPlayer isPlaying])
{
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Play Icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [audioPlayer pause];
    [self pauseTimer];
}else{
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [audioPlayer play];
    [self resumeTimer];
if(isFirstTime == YES)
    {
     self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:11.0
                                         target:self
                                         selector:@selector(displayviewsAction:)
                                         userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:NO];
        isFirstTime  = NO;
    }         
    } 
    }
```

This is how displayviewsAction loads 11 view controllers one after another at different time intervals

```
- (void)displayviewsAction:(id)sender
 {  
 First *firstController = [[First alloc] init];
 firstController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
 CATransition *transitionAnimation = [CATransition animation];
 [transitionAnimation setDuration:1];
 [transitionAnimation setType:kCATransitionFade];
 [transitionAnimation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];
 [self.view.layer addAnimation:transitionAnimation forKey:kCATransitionFade];
 [self.view addSubview:firstController.view];
 [self.view addSubview:toolbar];
 [firstController release];   
 self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:23 target:self selector:@selector(Second) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];     

 }

 -(void)Second 
{
Second *secondController = [[Second alloc] init];
secondController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
CATransition *transitionAnimation = [CATransition animation];
[transitionAnimation setDuration:1];
[transitionAnimation setType:kCATransitionReveal];
[transitionAnimation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];
[self.view.layer addAnimation:transitionAnimation forKey:kCATransitionReveal];
[self.view addSubview:secondController.view]; 
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
[secondController release];
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:27 target:self selector:@selector(Third) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

And that is how starting image animation within the view controller

```
// Displays UIImageView
UIImageView* ImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 300, 235)];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];
// load all the frames of our animation
ImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:    
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"1a.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"1b.png"],
                                nil];

 // all frames will execute in 25 seconds
 ImageView.animationDuration = 25;
// start animating
[ImageView startAnimating];
ImageView.layer.borderWidth = 2;
ImageView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor];
[ImageView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[ImageView.layer setCornerRadius:15.0f];
[baseView addSubview:ImageView];
```

Now if someone can guide me how to pause this slideshow of `UIImage animation` when this `NSTimer` pauses.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use the code provided by apple to pause and resume your animation.

```
-(void)pauseLayer:(CALayer*)layer
{
CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
layer.speed = 0.0;
layer.timeOffset = pausedTime;
}

-(void)resumeLayer:(CALayer*)layer
{
CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer timeOffset];
layer.speed = 1.0;
layer.timeOffset = 0.0;
layer.beginTime = 0.0;
CFTimeInterval timeSincePause = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil] - pausedTime;
layer.beginTime = timeSincePause;
}
```

And to get the CALayer to pass to the pauseLayer function, you can use the following code.

```
CALayer *player = ImageView.layer;
[self pauseLayer:player];
```

Hope it helps you.