# Animating Images Using an Array

Tags: animation, uiimage

I am animating some images using an array like this

```
NSArray *weatherFrames = [NSArray array];
weatherFrames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
             [UIImage imageWithData:Data1],
             [UIImage imageWithData:Data2],
             [UIImage imageWithData:Data3],
             [UIImage imageWithData:Data4],
             [UIImage imageWithData:Data5],                 
             nil];
weatherImage.animationImages = weatherFrames;
weatherImage.animationDuration = 10.00;
weatherImage.animationRepeatCount = 1;
[weatherImage release];
```

What I want to be able to do is Pause the animation when someone triggers a call (i.e from an IBAction). Is this possible or is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I copied the solution from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11103227/pause-uiimageview-animation).

```
-(void)pauseLayer:(CALayer*)layer
{
    CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
    layer.speed = 0.0;
    layer.timeOffset = pausedTime;
}

-(void)resumeLayer:(CALayer*)layer
{
    CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer timeOffset];
    layer.speed = 1.0;
    layer.timeOffset = 0.0;
    layer.beginTime = 0.0;
    CFTimeInterval timeSincePause = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil] - pausedTime;
    layer.beginTime = timeSincePause;
}
```

And to get the CALayer to pass to the pauseLayer function, you can use the following code.

```
CALayer *player = ImageView.layer;
[self pauseLayer:player];
```