# How to continue UIImageView animation after didEnterBackground?

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview, calayer

I have a simple UIImageView (`myimageview`) loaded with an NSArray(`animationArray`) of images for animation (in my `ViewController.m)`:

```
[self.myimageview setAnimationImages:self.animationArray];
[self.myimageview setAnimationDuration:[self durationTime]];
[self.myimageview setAnimationRepeatCount: 1];
[self.myimageview startAnimating];
```

I know where to use stopAnimating, etc.. However I have weird problem. When the screen locks then nothing happens to my animation. Anything works like a charm. It continue after I unlock the screen.

However when my app goes in to **Background mode** then the whole animation stops (my animations are 2-3 minutes long, thus it is not acceptable). I've searched a little and found this topic:

[How to pause a UIImageView animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253247/how-to-pause-a-uiimageview-animation)

Where it says to use this code:

```
UIView *viewBeingAnimated = //your view that is being animated
viewBeingAnimated.frame = [[viewBeingAnimated.layer presentationLayer] frame];
[viewBeingAnimated.layer removeAllAnimations];
//when user unpauses, create new animation from current position.
```

Now I'm trying to implement this to my code in AppDelegate.m

```
// in -(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:
self.viewController.myimageview.frame = [[self.myimageview.frenchPress.layer presentationLayer] frame];
```

However i got this **issue within XCode** (for the line above) and I can't further continue:

```
AppDelegate.m:40:47: Receiver type 'CALayer' for instance message is a forward declaration
```

I'm saving the time if I exit into the background to the value: `self.currentDate` (just for sidenote, in case we need it).

How can i pause and play the animation without interruptions?

Answer (score 3):

In order to get access to all the messages and properties of `CALayer`, you have to include its corresponding framework header:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

This will hopefully eliminate the warning.

Comment: Thanks for the comment that solved the header problem, however I don't know how to unpause from the frame I got know. Any tips that would me help?

Comment: @FatihArslan try `viewBeingAnimated.animationImages = nil;`

Comment: This will set my images to nil. I already have an array set before. Will this not destroy my images? If i call this, then how do I continue from the latest frame.

Comment: @FatihArslan you can also try `[viewBeingAnimated stopAnimating];`.

Comment: I think I cant explain myself to you. For my first snippet. Say I already called `startAnimating`. Then I go into background, I save the latest frame i got. Then what. Should I call `startAnimating` again on the same view, what is the procedure?

Comment: @FatihArslan yes, to continue the animation, call startAnimating again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16324/discussion-between-fatih-arslan-and-h2co3)